# Is there an easy way to remove overlapping faces?

Tags: mesh, faces, topology, geometry

Is there an easy way to remove overlapping faces? In the example remove doubles doesn't work

[image: example]

You might be able to do the following: <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces. <kbd>X</kbd> > *Only Faces*. <kbd>F</kbd> to create faces, but after deleting the faces I'm left with something like this.

[image: comment 1]

If I press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all and then press <kbd>F</kbd> to create faces then there are still overlapping.

Blend file[image]

Comment: You might be able to do the following: `A` to select all faces. `X` > _Only Faces_. `F` to create faces.

Comment: Respond in the question (couldn't add pictures in comments).

Comment: Also in the 2nd image note where the vertices are

Comment: It looks to me like your problems are with the n-gons. Try `Select > Select All by Trait > Select Faces by Sides`. Then use greater than 4 vertices (delete these n-gons).

Comment: It doesn't work :/

Comment: What's the criteria that defines the faces that should be deleted? Normal orientation? Is the grid pictured in the second image the edge distrubution you are aiming for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on what kind of topology you are looking for you can use grid fill.

Select the outer edgges (Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> click and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> click)

Invert the selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>)

Delete edges and Faces

Then do Grid Fill and play with Span and Offset to adjust the grid.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is <kbd>X</kbd> - Limited dissolve. One beautiful big Ngon.

[image: Limited Dissolve plus Grid]

**Updated the GIF:** pycoder indicated that cegaton's solution for Grid Fill gave the desired topography. This is also just a speed improvement to avoid a lot of edge clicking...

Comment: This is nice and easy, but the topology is really bad compared to the result of cegaton's answer using the grid fill tool.

Answer (score 1):

In the 3D viwport, in edit mode, choose wireframe option and face select mode. Now the median point of the vertices of each face will be visible as a black sqare. Select one face, and switch to vertex select mode. Now the face you selected will still be selected, but you will also see the vertices which define it's bounds. Press the <kbd>H</kbd>  key to hide those vertices, and the face to selected and all faces containing any of the vertices of the edge its face will be hidden. If you then switch back to face select mode, you will see the selection points for the overlapping faces and delete them in the usual manner. If there are more overlapping faces, repeat the process of selecting the center of the face in face select mode, switching to vertex select mode, hiding the vertices of the face and selecting and deleting the faces you want to eliminate.

When you have completed the deletion(s), unhide the hidden vertices using the key combination <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.

NOTE: sometimes I find it useful or necessary to toggle between wireframe and solid shading in the viewport when hiding vertices.

ALSO NOTE: Sometimes it's not easy because it's tedious and time consuming.