# Mesh duplicated itself under current mesh

Tags: mesh, vertices

Hey my mesh duplicated itself underneath the current mesh (somehow)and now you can see the graphical errors through the view-port, I am unable to remove doubles, and even unable to click drag the other mesh since its set as one part, and can not be separated since it is one.I do know selecting linked grabs all the mesh and deletes the whole thing, I need to delete the layer below, which is identical to the original layer

[image: Duplicates under old mesh]

Comment: Select linked, ctrl+L

Comment: This question is also answered by the answer to [question 61697](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61697/). While the two questions have the same answer, they are not, in my oponion, the same question.

Comment: It still deletes the whole project.

Comment: so, both meshes are connected... check the selected amount/amount of vertices on the top bar (after ctrl+L), and of course, select only one vertex before ctrl+L

Comment: Still Maximum/Maximum can I send you my work on this?

Comment: I had this once and the 2nd was in the next layer.  If you can locate each copy/version in the layout list, can you possibly unlink it (right click on it's entry?  Then try and grab it, move it to another layer if it hasn't disappeared.